# Bltoolkit oracle clob type

Tags: oracle, clob, bltoolkit

I use bltoolkit as orm and i had a problem with clob type.

I have a long string value and i got error while update operation.

> Error: ORA01704 - String literal too long.

Checked table and my column type is clob.
There is no clob option in bltoolkit table class design.
I set this column like that:

```
[MapField("MSG_BODY")]
public string MsgBody { get; set; }
```

What is wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

I find a solution, post only clob columns and it works !

```
 //update only body
  value = db.Schedule
 .Where(x => x.Rowversion == _zaman
  && x.ScheduleId == this.ScheduleId)

 .Set(x => x.Rowversion, x => _zaman)
 .Set(x => x.MsgBody, x => this.MsgBody)
 .Update();
```